# How can LibreOffice forbid me to paste from clipboard?

Tags: libreoffice, clipboard

I have a rather interesting problem.
I've been having an issue with LO for some time now, sometimes
it does not allow me to save documents, giving me a warning saying
"Cannot Save File: locked by 'unnknown user'" or someting similar.
Now when I want to save the text in the document and paste it into a
new file to workaround the issue [this has worked two or three times]
I cannot paste to the new .odt file I created. I also cannot paste
into any other application, be it gedit or a browser using Google Docs.
I am sort of lost here, as I really need the text from my clipboard.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

With the document closed, look in the folder which contains it. If there is a `lock file` associated with the document, delete it.

Also, there may be one in  `~/.config` or `~/.libreoffice/X`

Replace the X with your libreoffice version.  Make sure that you're able to view hidden files, to be able to find the one you're looking for.